# How do i change the html element dynamically while iterating from database

Tags: php

I am using a table to iterate the data from the database in a table. my html code is

```
    <table id="tablesorter"> 
        <thead> 
           <tr> 
           <th>Name</th> 
           <th>Location</th> 
           <th>Email</th> 
           <th>Phone</th> 
           </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
           <tr> 
           <td>Your Name</td> 
           <td>Somewhere</td> 
           <td>test@test.com</td> 
           <td>9999999999</td> 
           </tr> 
        <tr class="trow"> 
           <td>Your Name</td> 
           <td>Somewhere</td> 
           <td>test@test.com</td> 
           <td>9999999999</td>  
           </tr> 
           </tbody> 
   </table>
```

In my HTML table i am using a class for a table row to style it for every second table row. now while fetching the data from the database i want to make sure it does the same thing. it should add the class trow for every second table row.

what would be the logic behind this using with while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you could just use a ternary statement to set and unset the class variable as it loops through printing each row:

```
$class = ($class=='trow')?'':'trow';
<tr class="<?= $class ?>"> 
<td>Your Name</td> 
<td>Somewhere</td> 
<td>test@test.com</td> 
<td>9999999999</td> 
</tr>
```

So that each time a row is printed the `$class` variable would toggle between `trow` and nothing.

I use this logic when creating lists that export to excel quite often

Comment: wow so simple and easy to understand logic, that was brilliant answer and just the kind of solution i was looking for. thank you very much. :)

Comment: No problem, Ibrahim.  The ternary has become by best friend of late

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is what you want to do:

1. Use a counter variable to keep track of the row you're at
2. On each row, check if the row counter is even. The easiest way to do this is with the modulo operator `%`.

   ```
   6 % 2 == 0 // true
   5 % 2 == 1 // true
   4 % 2 == 1 // false
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a simple state machine:

```
$evens = FALSE;
while($row = fetch_from_db()) {
     $evens = !$evens; // invert the even/odd flag
     $rowtype = ($evens === TRUE) ? ' class="trow"' : '';
     echo <<<EOL
<tr{$rowtype}>
   <td>etc...
</tr>

EOL;
}
```

Since `$evens` starts out false, on the first row it's inverted to true, which sets `$rowtype` to 'trow'. On the second row, it's inverted back to false, `$rowtype` becomes empty. On the 3rd row, we're back to true/trow, and so on, ping-ponging back and forth.